# Multiple possible types for a serializable struct's field

Tags: rust, traits, serde

I'm writing a simple bookmark manager which will save data in a JSON format like this;

```
{
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Social",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "Facebook",
                    "url": "https://facebook.com",
                    "faviconUrl": "",
                    "tags": [],
                    "keyword": "",
                    "createdAt": 8902351,
                    "modifiedAt": 90981235
                }
            ],
            "createdAt": 235123534,
            "modifiedAt": 23531235
        }
    ]
}
```

I've tried to write `children` field to allow two possible types (`Directory` and `Bookmark`) by creating a common `Entry` trait but I'm hitting a wall as I can't implement `Serialize` trait from `serde` for the `Entry` trait.

```
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize, Serializer};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Root<'a> {
    children: Vec<&'a dyn Entry>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Directory<'a> {
    name: String,
    created_at: u64,
    children: Vec<&'a dyn Entry>,
    modified_at: u64
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Bookmark {
    name: String,
    url: String,
    favicon_url: String,
    tags: Vec<String>,
    keyword: String,
    created_at: u64,
    modified_at: u64,
}

trait Entry {
    fn is_directory(&self) -> bool;
}

impl Entry for Directory<'_> {
    fn is_directory(&self) -> bool {
        true
    }
}

impl Entry for Bookmark {
    fn is_directory(&self) -> bool {
        false
    }
}

// can't do this
impl Serialize for Entry {}
```

Is it even possible to make this work or I should create a different structure which wouldn't contain a field with multiple possible values? I was thinking about loading the JSON as `HashMap<String, serde_json::Value>` and looping through the hash map but I was wondering if there is some more elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just make the Entry an enum rather than a trait, and change the `&dyn Entry` to just `Entry`, then everything should just work, except you will end up with one extra level in your JSON, and an additional tag entry telling you what type the entry is. As Masklinn pointed out in the comments, the case is also incorrect, but can be fixed using `#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]`.

```
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Root {
    children: Vec<Entry>,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Directory {
    name: String,
    created_at: u64,
    children: Vec<Entry>,
    modified_at: u64,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
struct Bookmark {
    name: String,
    url: String,
    favicon_url: String,
    tags: Vec<String>,
    keyword: String,
    created_at: u64,
    modified_at: u64,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "camelCase")]
enum Entry {
    Directory(Directory),
    Bookmark(Bookmark),
}
```

If you really don't want the extra level and the tag, then you can use the [serde(untagged)](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged) annotation to `Entry`.

```
#[derive(Deserialize, Serialize, Debug)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum Entry {
    Directory(Directory),
    Bookmark(Bookmark),
}
```

---

If you need a bit more flexibility you can create an intermediate struct `BookmarkOrDirectory` that contains all the fields of both, with the fields that only occur in one as `Option` and then implement `TryFrom<BookmarkOrDirectory>` for `Entry` and use [serde(try_from=...)](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#try_from)  and [serde(into=...)](https://serde.rs/container-attrs.html#into) to convert to/from the appropriate form. An example implementation is below. It compiles, but has a few `todo!` scattered in it, and uses `String` as an error type, which is hacky - and is of course untested.

```
use core::convert::TryFrom;
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct Root {
    children: Vec<Entry>,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Directory {
    name: String,
    created_at: u64,
    children: Vec<Entry>,
    modified_at: u64,
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct Bookmark {
    name: String,
    url: String,
    favicon_url: String,
    tags: Vec<String>,
    keyword: String,
    created_at: u64,
    modified_at: u64,
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Clone)]
#[serde(try_from = "BookmarkOrDirectory", into = "BookmarkOrDirectory")]
enum Entry {
    Directory(Directory),
    Bookmark(Bookmark),
}

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
struct BookmarkOrDirectory {
    name: String,
    url: Option<String>,
    favicon_url: Option<String>,
    tags: Option<Vec<String>>,
    keyword: Option<String>,
    created_at: u64,
    modified_at: u64,
    children: Option<Vec<Entry>>,
}

impl BookmarkOrDirectory {
    pub fn to_directory(self) -> Result<Directory, (Self, String)> {
        // Check all the fields are there
        if !self.children.is_some() {
            return Err((self, "children is not set".to_string()));
        }
        // TODO: Check extra fields are not there
        Ok(Directory {
            name: self.name,
            created_at: self.created_at,
            children: self.children.unwrap(),
            modified_at: self.modified_at,
        })
    }
    pub fn to_bookmark(self) -> Result<Bookmark, (Self, String)> {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl TryFrom<BookmarkOrDirectory> for Entry {
    type Error = String;
    fn try_from(v: BookmarkOrDirectory) -> Result<Self, String> {
        // Try to parse it as direcory
        match v.to_directory() {
            Ok(directory) => Ok(Entry::Directory(directory)),
            Err((v, mesg1)) => {
                // if that fails try to parse it as bookmark
                match v.to_bookmark() {
                    Ok(bookmark) => Ok(Entry::Bookmark(bookmark)),
                    Err((_v, mesg2)) => Err(format!("unable to convert to entry - not a bookmark since '{}', not a directory since '{}'", mesg2, mesg1))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

impl Into<BookmarkOrDirectory> for Bookmark {
    fn into(self) -> BookmarkOrDirectory {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Into<BookmarkOrDirectory> for Directory {
    fn into(self) -> BookmarkOrDirectory {
        todo!()
    }
}

impl Into<BookmarkOrDirectory> for Entry {
    fn into(self) -> BookmarkOrDirectory {
        match self {
            Entry::Bookmark(bookmark) => bookmark.into(),
            Entry::Directory(directory) => directory.into(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not actually need to do anything, serde supports "structural" matching of enums using [the `serde(untagged)` annotation](https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html#untagged). demo: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=73fe7b52d883d4ffed36d05ea6bf4f90

Comment: By "anything" I mean all the complex faffing around with an extra struct and a bunch of conversions. Instead it's sufficient to mark `Entry` as `serde(untagged)`, derive `Serialize` and `Deserialize` on `Directory` and `Bookmark`, and mark both as `serde(rename_all = "camelCase")`.

Comment: The one drawback of `untagged` is that [it can be pretty slow](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/issues/1381).

Comment: @Masklinn thanks, I didn't know that existed  --- I've incorporated that suggestion into the body now.